# Calendar.createEventAsync crashes on android only Expo

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to add an event to the device's calendar, on iOS it works perfect but on Android, the app crashes and I get this error.

```
    22956/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #6
   Process: …., PID: 22713
   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
       at expo.modules.calendar.CalendarModule.createRemindersForEvent(CalendarModule.java:869)
       at expo.modules.calendar.CalendarModule.saveEvent(CalendarModule.java:751)
       at expo.modules.calendar.CalendarModule.access$500(CalendarModule.java:34)
       at expo.modules.calendar.CalendarModule$6.run(CalendarModule.java:161)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)”
```

this is my code :

```
   let isoFormattedStartDate = moment(event.eventStartDate).toISOString();
let isoFormattedEndDate = moment(event.eventEndDate).toISOString();

Calendar.createEventAsync(Calendar.DEFAULT, {
  title: name,
  startDate: isoFormattedStartDate,
  endDate: isoFormattedEndDate,
  location: location,
  timeZone: "GMT+1",
  alarms: [{relativeOffset: -1}, {relativeOffset: -1440}]
})
  .then((event) => {
    console.log("Calendar.createEventAsync success: ", event);
    Alert.alert("Added To Calendar");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Calendar.createEventAsync failure: ", error);
  });
```

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"expo": "33.0.7",
"expo-calendar": "~5.0.1",
"expo-cli": "^2.19.5",
 "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
```

...
         },

I'm not sure why its only crashing on Android. Any help would be greatly appreciated it! thank you

Comment: The value of 'date' seems to come from an integer value.

Comment: Remove the "alarms" then it will work.

Comment: Hi @omprakash8080 thanks for your answer. The alarms is main feature I want. I want people to be reminded of an upcoming event 1 day & 2 hours before it on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is here.

https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/5134

We can expect the fix in expo SDk 35.

Comment: Hi Rajendran, Thank you very much your answer. I am doing something else at the moment so I will have to come back to this bug at another time. when is sdk planned to be released?